# Start handler thread at zero seconds

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

I have a method that needs to be executed every minute, but I need to start this thread at exactly 00 seconds of a minute (on the watch), as it updates the screen based on time.

**My handler code is here:**

```
//update bottom card every minute
private final static int INTERVAL = 1000 * 60; //1 minute
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

Runnable mHandlerTask = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateBottomCard();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, INTERVAL);
    }
};

public void startRepeatingTask(ArrayList<Meeting> meetingsOfToday)
{
    this.meetingsOfToday = meetingsOfToday;
    mHandlerTask.run();
}
```

In the main activity I have a call like this:

```
BottomCardController.getInstance(this).startRepeatingTask(meetingsSorted.get(TODAY_INDEX));
```

However, this call happens at random point in time, for example not at 14:12:00 - but at 14:12:41 instead, and I need it to be started at exactly 14:12:00 (hh:mm:ss). Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `startRepeatingTask()` calculate the time needed to wait until the next 'Minute' interval (ie 00 seconds) and delay the initial run until then.

Future runs will be delayed by 60 seconds (b/c of your `INTERVAL` delay) so they will run on the 00 mark.

```
public static long getNextMinuteTimestamp(){
        long timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double timeInSec = timeInMillis / 1000.0;
        double timeInMin = timeInSec / 60.0;
        return ((long) Math.ceil(timeInMin)) * 60 * 1000;
    }

public void startRepeatingTask(ArrayList<Meeting> meetingsOfToday)
{
    this.meetingsOfToday = meetingsOfToday;
    long delayAmt = getNextMinuteTimestamp() - System.currentTimeMillis();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mHandlerTask, delayAmt);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps an example, but overall this seems like the solution.

Comment: Your answer represents functionality in Java/Android that hasn't even been displayed in the question. Providing an example as to how you could actually get the time to the next minute and create the delay would be a full answer. And yes... it would require some math.